# Rose rosette starting?

Tags: diagnosis

My first scare. I am familiar with new red growth but this. I did just feed a few weeks ago and I am seeing a lot of new growth, new red growth, new green leaves on all my roses. This is a new plant this year and the canes are all small. Noticed last week this large cane all of a sudden. It’s thoenier, big, and even flat. There is a cluster of buds on top as well. I have never experienced or seen RRD. Just online. It is in a pot so I did move it to work away from all my others. 
![image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 3):

It does look awfully like Rose Rosette virus infection I'm afraid. Fasciation of that main stem might mean its just fasciation (https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=525) but the excessive thorns on it are usually diagnostic of Rose Rosette. You don't say which variety of rose this is, but Rose  Rosette is  much more common on multiflora varieties, see here http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/diseases/viruses/rose-rosette.aspx

Luckily, it's in a pot, but the mites that cause this problem may be present in your garden - you've already isolated the rose away from others, so you could risk just waiting to see what happens, or not take the risk and destroy this plant asap; as you've moved it out of your garden, so long as there are no roses where you've taken it, I'd wait and see what happens. At the same time as keeping a close watch on other roses you have at home...

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community. Regarding your vigorous shoot, it really depends on where it originates from on the rose bush. Most roses these days are grafted; the root part should grow only roots and the green top part must grow only shoots. In short, if your shoot is growing from a point above the graft union then you are lucky and keep it, but if it originates from the root part then get rid of it. In this case cut it off as close to the point of origin as possible.

It is not unusual for top and bottom of grafted plants to get out of balance so that one dominates. Usually the root has a problem pushing nourishment up to the flowering part and in frustration sends out its own flowering part. We don't want to encourage this behaviour since soon the root can take over the flowering with its own undesirable characteristics, with the result that the part you really want to do well fades away to nothing and all you have left is briar.

In your case the fact that the new shoot has five leaflets argues in favour of its coming from the root, but that will be for you to verify, carefully. Prompt investigation is called for.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled some soil away and it does not appear to be coming from the roots. I have taken new pics of it today. Still some red on the undersides of some leaves. [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Just to point out that the red colour is not "a problem" in itself. The underlying colour of the whole plant is red. The green colour that you see is the chlorophyll which is produced for photosynthesis, which masks the red. New growth often looks red, simply because the plant is growing faster than new chlorophyll is being produced. As the growth matures, and more chlorophyll is produced, it would normally turn green. A plant growing in very bright light will tend to retain the red colour, because less chlorophyll is needed to produce all the nutrients it needs in brighter light conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the welcome. It is an own-root Disneyland Florinunda. There are no other flowers at work and none closeby. Hoping if it does turn out to be RRD, it was far enough away from the others at home. It was in a rock garden alone to cover up some uglies.